# SVN - create a new repository and add trunk and branches from an old repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I'd like to rename my SVN repository.  I've tried an svn copy command to copy from one repository to another, but this doesn't work:

```
F:\Old>svn copy https://devserver2.sockltd.local/svn/Dantooine https://devserver2.sockltd.local/svn/IOCPTest

svn: Repository moved permanently to 'https://devserver2.sockltd.local/'; please relocate
```

When I have a look at the list of repositories IOCPTest doesn't exist.

Is there some way to rename a repository, or should I just export the old repository and dump its content into the new one.  The problem is, with that approach, I'll loose branches and revision history.

thanks

Comment: How are you hosting your repository? Apache, svnserve?

Comment: Do you want to clone a repo (question title) or rename a repo (question body)? Why do you say *it doesn't work* if the command prints "Repository moved permanently"?

Comment: I'd like to rename the repository.  Having failed to do so, I was trying to copy the repository.  The command claimed to have worked.  But it didn't.  No such repository exists!

Comment: No, the 'moved permanently / please relocate' is an error message to tell you that your working copy needs updating - I don't think it's a success message here (it means you need to do an `svn switch --relocate`). Quite why it's telling you that for this operation I don't know. It's not possible to do that sort of repository manipulation from the SVN client - you need to do it on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a feature on the main application window of the VisualSVN server - "Import Existing Repository..."

It automates the task of copying one repository to a new one, while at the same time giving the facilty to specify the new repository name.  It works fine for my needs and copies the branches and revision history too :)

Comment: As a general rule, a repository is only a directory and it doesn't track/care/know what its name is. So you can normally rename the directory and you're done. The issue here is that VisualSVN Server provides some additional features on top of the repo (such as access control lists) and they'll be lost of you do a raw directory rename. As far as I know VisualSVN Server does not provide a GUI to make renames, but it provides (as you already guessed) a feature to clone repos.

Answer (score 0):

This depends how VisualSVN is organising your repository(ies) under the covers. If Dantooine is a separate repository (i.e. has its own independent version numbers) then easiest thing to do would be to copy / rename the Dantooine directory on the server. The name isn't included in the repository data - as far as subversion is concerned that's just the URL for data transport, it recognises repositories by a GUID revprop - so a rename followed by a `svn switch --relocate` on your clients should be enough to move it.

If instead you want to create a complete copy / fork of the repository you can again just copy the Dantooine directory.

Or if you actually want to copy / filter the branches from the reposistory you can use `svnadmin dump` to make a backup of the old repository and the `svndumpfilter` python script to strip out branches you don't want, then `svnadmin load` to load the filtered backup into a fresh repository.

All of this might not be the VisualSVN way to do things, though - I've never used that myself.